# Check if the parameter is passed and return relevant data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to write a method that always returns the user data irrespective of the studentID that is being passed as well in the argument. But if the studentID is passed, I then want to get additional data and add that to the one I am already receiving. Here is what my code looks like

```js
async getData(token, studentId) {
    let student;

    try {
        student = await this.getDataWithoutID(token);
    } catch(error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
          
    if (studentId) {
        //student param for getDataWithID is from the student object above
        let studentId = this.getDataWithID(student, studentId);
        return studentId;
    }
    
    return student;
}
```

As you see above, if the condition is true, I want both the studenId object and student object to be returned. Is there a better way to do this? TIA

Comment: A better way would be to pass it as a query to whatever DB you are using, and let it happen at the DB level.

Comment: it does not involve any DB queries/calls, instead makes calls to an endpoint to get the data

Comment: Yes I am talking about that endpoint, do you have control over the backend? it is more logical to send one query from the client, and check for parameters on the server.

Comment: If you do not have control over the server endpoint \ api, i'd suggest you edit your question to specify that. (and perhaps change the node.js tag to whatever framework you are using at the client).

Comment: He could also use node.js as a client :)

Comment: Javascript does not support multiple returns from function. So you might want to wrap your results into a single object as Christos Panagiotakopoulos suggested.

Comment: @OleksandrTkalenko `Javascript does not support multiple returns from function` What makes you say that? It definitely does? You can't return more than once, but you can definitely branch.

Comment: @ChrisG Probably I was not totally accurate in my expression. By multiple returns I meant returning multiple values at once. Like it's designed in golang for example https://golangdocs.com/multiple-return-values-in-golang-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might be what you need:

```js
async getData(token, studentId) {
    try {
        const student = await this.getDataWithoutID(token);
        if (studentId) {
            const extraData = await this.getDataWithID(studentId); // Here you fetch the extraData using the studentId
            return { ...student, ...extraData }; // Here you "merge" the two objects
        }

        return student;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

Your try/catch block should encompass the whole function not just a part of it. You shouldn't return a variable outside the try/catch block.

Comment: should the `return student` be inside the try block? @Christos

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you. The `return student;` statement **is** and **should** be inside the `try` block yes.

Comment: I think you are missing a parenthesis after the return statement and before the catch block @Christos

Comment: You are correct, I was missing a bracket `}` before the catch statement. Thanks for pointing this out! I edited my answer.